# Pointers doesn't give me same value

Tags: c++, pointers

i'm learning how to program in c++ and i'm facing into a problem:
I have a struct called Professeur, where Cours and Etudiant are other structs (not the problem here) :

```
struct Professeur {
        std::string Nom;
        int Ancien;
        Cours* ListeDeCours;
        Etudiant* ListeDEtudiant;
        Professeur* Suivant;
      };
```

In my program i read a file and then store the data in these structure. However when i want to display the info stored in the "Suivant" Professeur i have a problem, see :

The data file :

```
Prof1
1
Cours11
Cours12
Cours13
&
Etudiant11
Etudiant12
Etudiant13
$
Prof2
2
Cours21
Cours22
Cours23
&
Etudiant21
Etudiant22
Etudiant23
$
```

And the output :

```
2
1
1
6304032
```

As you can see, newprof->Ancien don't give me the same value and i don't know why as i don' modify it (i suppose). So i did a test program, where i create my struct by myself and it work perfectly:

I searched everything but i don't know why it's not working.. Could someone take a look ? Thanks a lot

Here is code where the problem should be located :
test.cpp

```
ifstream fichier;
vector<DossierProfesseur::Professeur> ContainerProf;
vector<DossierProfesseur::Cours> ContainerCours;
vector<DossierProfesseur::Etudiant> ContainerEtudiant;
DossierProfesseur::DossierProfesseur(string FP){
    fichier.open(FP);
    if (fichier.is_open() ){
        Professeur premier = DossierProfesseur::CreationListeProfesseur();
        tete = &premier;
        Professeur *newprof = DossierProfesseur::getNextProf(tete);

        cout<< newprof->Ancien<<"\n";
        cout<< tete->Ancien<<"\n";
        cout<< tete->Ancien<<"\n";
        cout<< newprof->Ancien<<"\n";
    }
    else{
        printf("Error while openning file");
    }
}

DossierProfesseur::Professeur* DossierProfesseur::getNextProf(DossierProfesseur::Professeur* prof){
    return prof->Suivant;
}


DossierProfesseur::Professeur DossierProfesseur::CreationListeProfesseur(){
    Professeur prof;
    Cours cours;
    Etudiant etudiant;
    if(!fichier.eof()){ //Fin du fichier
        getline(fichier,prof.Nom);
        string ancien;
        getline(fichier,ancien);
        prof.Ancien = stoi(ancien);
        Professeur nextProf = DossierProfesseur::CreationListeProfesseur();
        prof.Suivant = &nextProf;
    }
    else{
        prof.Nom = string();
        prof.Ancien = 0;
        prof.ListeDeCours = NULL;
        prof.ListeDEtudiant = NULL;
        prof.Suivant = NULL;
    }
    ContainerProf.push_back(prof);
return ContainerProf.back();
}

int main()
{
    string dest = "FP.txt";
    DossierProfesseur dos (dest);
    return 0;
}
```

test.h :

```
#ifndef DossierProfesseur_h
#define DossierProfesseur_h
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>

  class DossierProfesseur
  {
    public:
      DossierProfesseur(std::string FP);

      struct Cours{
        std::string Sigle;
        Cours* Suivant;
      };
      struct Etudiant{
        std::string Sigle;
        Etudiant* suivant;
      };
      struct Professeur {
        std::string Nom;
        int Ancien;
        Cours* ListeDeCours;
        Etudiant* ListeDEtudiant;
        Professeur* Suivant;
      };
      Professeur CreationListeProfesseur();
      Professeur *getNextProf(Professeur *prof);
      Professeur* tete;
    private:


  };
#endif
```

Edit :
Using vectors, i have the same output as previously:

```
2 - 0x7ffe26c10520
1
1
6320480 - 0x7ffe26c10520
```

They point to the same adress, but have different values
To use vectors i used this :
vector ContainerProf; as a global variable 
And then in CreationListeEtudiant :
Insted of returning prof, i return this :

```
ContainerProf.push_back(prof);
    return ContainerProf.back();
```

Did i do something wrong?

Comment: Thats a lot of code for us to read through. If you would [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that would probably help both you and us find the problem.

Comment: sure sorry, i put all these because i don't know wher my problem is located :/ I'll edit the code so it'll be more viewable

Comment: Don't worry, it's incredibly common to not know where the problem is located.  The instructions for creating a minimal example show how to do so, which includes how to locate the problems. (A) it makes it far easier for us to help you, so you get more help, or (B) it teaches you how to solve the problem yourself, making you a better developer.

Answer (score 1):

```
DossierProfesseur::Professeur DossierProfesseur::CreationListeProfesseur(){
    Professeur prof;
    Cours cours;
 ...
        cours = DossierProfesseur::CreationListeCours();
        prof.ListeDeCours = &cours;
        etudiant = DossierProfesseur:
 ...
    return prof;
}
```

You create `cours` as a local object inside this function, so `cours` will cease to exist when this function returns. Yet you stash the address of `cours` inside the `prof` object you return by value. So you are returning an object to the caller that contains a pointer to an object that no longer exists. Attempting to dereference that pointer is disastrous.

Please don't use pointers this way. It makes managing the lifetimes of objects extremely difficult.

Comment: thanks for your answer, in that way what should i do to create those objects as i don't know the quantity of "Professeur" i have?

Comment: Sounds like you need `std::vector`

Comment: i'll try to implement it and i'll come back to you, thanks for the answer

Comment: Ok, just try to implement it, however i have the same error, the same value is returned. Go check my post at the end